# php переключение версий

Tags: php, ubuntu

После обновления до Ubuntu 16.04 из коробки установлен **php7**. Для моих проектов использую **php5.6**. Подскажите, как управлять версиями, и использовать **php5.6** по умолчанию?

```
$ php -v
PHP 7.0.6-1+donate.sury.org~xenial+1 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies

$ whereis php
php: /usr/bin/php /usr/bin/php7.0 /usr/bin/php5.6 /usr/lib/php /etc/php /usr/share/php7.0-opcache /usr/share/php7.0-gd /usr/share/php /usr/share/php5.6-opcache /usr/share/php7.0-mcrypt /usr/share/php7.0-json /usr/share/php7.0-common /usr/share/php7.0-readline /usr/share/php5.6-json /usr/share/php7.0-xml /usr/share/php7.0-mysql /usr/share/php5.6-common /usr/share/php5.6-readline /usr/share/man/man1/php.1.gz
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

если эти пакеты установлены из официального репозитория, то используется механизм [альтернатив (alternatives)](https://wiki.debian.org/ru/DebianAlternatives) и `/usr/bin/php` является символической ссылкой (symlink) на `/etc/alternatives/php`, которая, в свою очередь, тоже является символической ссылкой на реальный исполняемый файл. в вашем случае — `/usr/bin/php7.0`.

«перенаправить» на другую альтернативу можно, например, так:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config php
```

если есть альтернативы, то будет предложен пронумерованный список альтернатив (в частности, с указанием пути к реальным файлам) с предложением ввести номер (из списка) для изменения текущего выбора альтернативы.

Answer (score 8):

Уже было. Странно, что не нашли. Сам пользуюсь:

устанавливаем с репозитория не официального (7.0 и 5.6):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php7.0 php5.6 php5.6-mysql php-gettext php5.6-mbstring php-mbstring php7.0-mbstring php-xdebug libapache2-mod-php5.6 libapache2-mod-php7.0
```

и переключаемся с помощью следующих команд (для Apache и для командной строки разные!!!):

php5.6 -> php7.0 :

Apache:

```
sudo a2dismod php5.6 ; sudo a2enmod php7.0 ; sudo service apache2 restart
```

CLI:

```
update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.0
```

php7.0 -> php5.6 :

Apache:

```
sudo a2dismod php7.0 ; sudo a2enmod php5.6 ; sudo service apache2 restart
```

CLI:

```
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php5.6
```

Answer (score 1):

Еще вариант, **phpenv** как менеджер версий:

https://github.com/phpenv/phpenv

- `$(phpenv version-name)` - текущая версия php;
- `~/.phpenv/versions/$(phpenv version-name)/etc/php.ini` - php.ini
  текущей версии php;
- `phpenv global 5.6.0` - использовать версию php 5.6.0.