# Вызываю команду python3 --version, получаю в ответ версию пайтона 2.7

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, python-3.8

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Версия пайтона 3.8 установлена как сделать так, чтобы python3 указывал не на  2.7 версию, а на 3.8

Comment: it will be better if you wrote in russian

Comment: Это русская версия stackoverflow, поэтому и вопрос должен быть на русском

Comment: Просто это мой первый вопрос, буду знать

Comment: очень интересно, почему питон вдруг в папке /bin, когда он обычно в /usr/bin. Никто не шалил в системе? я посмотрел вывод `ls /usr/bin/python* -al` ну и заодно `ls /usr/python* -al`

Comment: @KoVadim, поттеринг, великий и ужасный, так [развлекается](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/TheCaseForTheUsrMerge/).

Comment: воспользуйтесь [update-alternatives](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/521123/178576). если python3 там не зарегистрирован, то просто руками измените символическую ссылку: `$ sudo ln -sf python3.8 /usr/bin/python3`

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin кто его остановит?